# In shopify with laravel the APP is not loading

Tags: php, laravel-8, shopify-app

I am using laravel in shopify for custom App development.
Laravel => 8
package => laravel/ossiset

I have used this link to install:

```
https://clickysoft.com/shopify-laravel-app-development/
```

I have installed it successfully and i have notice some strange behaviour with the APP using with Specific URL.

When i logged into my shopify admin account the URL is:

```
https://admin.shopify.com/store/[STORE NAME]/products?selectedView=all
```

When i switch to App and click on my APP to load. It will stop and shows the URL:

```
https://admin.shopify.com/store/[STORE NAME]/apps/[APP NAME]
```

The App is working on this URL:

```
https://[STORE NAME].myshopify.com/admin/apps/[APP NAME]
```

Now, I want APP should work on this URL:

```
https://admin.shopify.com
```

As this APP is with Laravel It is using BLADE engine.

Hope any help me to find a solution.
Thank you

Comment: This seems to be a support question on how to manage apps and settings on your Shopify account. Start by contacting their support. We can help you if you have specific programming questions, but not how to configure third party services.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution to this issue.
So, what i made a mistake is i have install the old package which is abandoned. And try to make all the changes.

https://github.com/Kyon147/laravel-shopify/wiki/Installation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The package you are currently working on has been **`abandoned`**.
I know how to fix this problem. Replace your current package with this one, then work on it.

Official Doumentation:-
https://github.com/Kyon147/laravel-shopify

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34942849)